# Flutter create infinite ListView.builder scrolling both up and down

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a calendar interface with Flutter, but I can't figure out a way to make a ListView.builder that is infinite and can scroll both up (to previous dates) and down (to forward dates).

You can see it in the Google calendar app where you start it and you can scroll up and down through the calendar, with the starting point being the current date.

Comment: You need to show some work that you have done.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/infinite_listview might provide what you want

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'll try it out thanks for linking!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that's exactly what I'm looking for. If you want the credit post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a ready-to-use package that provides that functionality

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/infinite_listview

If you want to build your own the source is available.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It saved me a *lot* of work!